# Custom styled check box not loading style with dynamically loading content

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am using http://boedesign.com/blog/2008/06/08/imagetick-for-jquery/ to style a check box. My div structure is like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Check1</th>
     <th>Check2</th>
     <th>Name</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td><input class="accept" type="checkbox" value="check_1" name="accept_1" id="accept1"></td>

     <td><input class="process" type="checkbox" value="check_2" name="process_1" id="process1"></td>
     <td>donald</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

In my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
                  $("input[name='accept_1']").imageTick({
                        tick_image_path: { 
                            check_1: "/public/images/checkbox_full.png"
                            //"default": "images/gender/default_checked.jpg" //optional default can be used
                        },
                        no_tick_image_path: { 
                            check_1: "/public/images/checkbox_empty.png", 
                            //"default": "images/gender/default_unchecked.jpg" //optional default can be used
                        },
                        image_tick_class: "accept_1",
                    });
                });

            $(function() {
                   $("input[name='process_1']").imageTick({
                       tick_image_path: { 
                           check_1: "/public/images/checkbox_full.png"
                           //"default": "images/gender/default_checked.jpg" //optional default can be used
                       },
                       no_tick_image_path: { 
                           check_1: "/public/images/checkbox_empty.png", 
                           //"default": "images/gender/default_unchecked.jpg" //optional default can be used
                       },
                       image_tick_class: "process_1",
                   });
               });
```

I will load the contents of table via .load() method. But the checkboxes not styled with the images. It displays image only on first time page load. After that now displaying. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your plugin in the .load function callback:

```
$('#your_item').load(title, function(){
    $("input[name='accept_1']").imageTick({
        tick_image_path: { check_1: "/public/images/checkbox_full.png"},
        no_tick_image_path: { check_1: "/public/images/checkbox_empty.png"},
        image_tick_class: "accept_1",
    });

    $("input[name='process_1']").imageTick({
        tick_image_path: { check_1: "/public/images/checkbox_full.png"},
        no_tick_image_path: { check_1: "/public/images/checkbox_empty.png"},
        image_tick_class: "process_1",
    });
});
```